# Proof that Quantile Function characterizes Probability Distribution

Tags: probability-theory

The quantile function is defined as $Q(u)= \inf \{x: F(x) \geq u\}$.

It is well known the distribution function characterizes the probability distribution in the following sense

**Theorem** Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be two real valued random variables with distribution functions $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$ respectively. If $F_{1}(x)=F_{2}(x)$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ then $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ have the same probability distribution.

I want to prove that the quantile function also characterizes the probability distribution, this fact is stated as a corallary of the above theorem in this [book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RwsVdXuStIMC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=quantile+function+severini&source=bl&ots=9WHGOac6nq&sig=LyKeHQm3ur2knir5N8i8Ruu2tHc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zNd1UL6GNcGo0AWmhIHACg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=quantile%20function%20severini&f=false) (see Corallary 1.2 on p19):

**Corallary**: Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be two real valued random variables with quantile functions $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{2}$ respectively. If $Q_{1}(u)=Q_{2}(u)$, $\forall u\in\left(0,1\right)$ then $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ have the same probability distribution.

The proof in the [book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RwsVdXuStIMC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=quantile+function+severini&source=bl&ots=9WHGOac6nq&sig=LyKeHQm3ur2knir5N8i8Ruu2tHc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zNd1UL6GNcGo0AWmhIHACg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=quantile%20function%20severini&f=false) is based on the following facts

**Fact i**: $Q(F(x)) \leq x$.

**Fact ii**: $F( Q(u) ) \geq u$.

**Fact iii**: $Q(u) \leq x$ iff $u \leq F(x)$.

**Fact iv**: $Q(u)$ is nondecreasing.

But I think it is wrong. Assuming $F_{1}(x_0) < F_{2}(x_0)$ for some fixed $x_0$ the author sets out to prove that this leads to a contradiction. Using facts (i) and (iv) he shows $Q_{2}(F_1(x_0)) < Q_{2}(F_2(x_0)) \leq x_0$. Then he applies fact (iii) to obtain $F_{1}(x_0) \leq F_{2}(x_0)$. The author claims that this is a contradiction. But clearly its not and the argument proves nothing.

Am I missing something here? Does anyone know the correct proof to the corallary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be the correct proof. It is a direct proof as opposed to the incorrect proof by contradiction given in the book.

$Q_1(F_2(x_0))=Q_2(F_2(x_0)) \leq x_0$ (by part i)

hence

$F_1(x_0) \geq F_2(x_0)$ (by part iii)

Also

$Q_2(F_1(x_0))=Q_1(F_1(x_0)) \leq x_0$ by (by part i)

hence

$F_2(x_0) \geq F_1(x_0)$ (by part iii)

and ofcourse the only way both these conclusions can be true is if $F_1(x_0)=F_2(x_0)$.

Answer (score 2):

*Changed since version discussed in first five comments:*

The key line  in the proof of Corollary 1.2 in Severini's *Elements of Distribution Theory* book is

> Hence by part (iii) of Theorem 1.8, $F_2(x_0) \ge F_1(x_0)$ so that $F_1(x_0) \lt F_2(x_0)$ is impossible.

As you say,  $F_1(x_0) \lt F_2(x_0)$ in fact implies $F_1(x_0) \le F_2(x_0)$, i.e. $F_2(x_0) \ge F_1(x_0)$, so this is not a contradiction.

Comment: I have not miscopied part iii of the theorem. You have got one of the inequalities reversed in the above. But indeed if this was true it would prove the theorem.

Comment: @aukie: Try rereading theorem 1.8 from your Google link. Carefully.

Comment: @@Henry: This is what the book says. "$Q(t) \leq x$ iff $F(x)\geq t$". This is what you have written "$Q(t) \leq x$ iff $t \geq F(x)$". You have misread the second inequality.

Comment: @aukie - so I cannot read either; sorry.  But the proof of Corallary 1.2 still says $F_{1}(x_0) \ge F_{2}(x_0)$

Comment: @aukie: I am starting to see your point.

Comment: Am I reading the same book? The proof to corallary 1.2 says $F_2(x_0) \geq F_1(x_0)$ (3rd last line on p19, which is not a contradiction! so the proof is wrong). But in your last comment you claim the book says $F_1(x_0) \geq F_2(x_0)$. I am thoroughly confused!

Comment: The modified answer is still incorrect. If we have established $Q_2(F_1(x_0)) \leq x_0$, applying theorem 1.8 part (iii) simply yields $F_2(x_0) \geq F_1(x_0)$ which does not contradict the assumption $F_1(x_0) < F_2(x_0)$ so this argument proves nothing

Comment: Answer changed radically.

Comment: Hmmm I wonder what the correct proof is. I have read the quantile function characterizes the probability distribution in a few places, But i've never actually seen a working proof of the fact.